# Cannot read pdf generated by iText

Tags: java, pdf, servlets, itext

This is my code which generates pdf:

```
public String generateList( Group group, List<GroupTerm> terms, List<Child> children, int begin, int finish )
{
    String pathForList = "C:\\...\\List.pdf";

    File filePath = new File( pathForList );
    filePath.delete();

    try
    {

        Document document = new Document( PageSize.A4.rotate() );

        PdfWriter.getInstance( document, new FileOutputStream( pathForList ) );

        document.open();

        // CONTENT

        BaseFont helvetica = BaseFont.createFont( BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED );
        Font helvetica9 = new Font( helvetica, 9 );
        Font helvetica9bold = new Font( helvetica, 9, Font.BOLD );

        Paragraph paragraph1 =
            new Paragraph( "Godziny: " + group.getStartHours() + "-" + group.getFinishHours() + "  Miejsce: " + group.getPlace()
                + "  Grupa wiekowa: " + group.getAgeGroupName() + "  Poziom: " + group.getLevel() + "  Instruktor: " + group.getInstructor(),
                           helvetica9bold );

        paragraph1.setAlignment( Element.ALIGN_LEFT );

        document.add( paragraph1 );
        document.add( new Paragraph( " " ) ); 

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable( 12 ); // 12 columns.

        PdfPCell cell01 = new PdfPCell( new Paragraph( "Imię", helvetica9 ) );
        PdfPCell cell02 = new PdfPCell( new Paragraph( "Nazwisko", helvetica9 ) );
        table.addCell( cell01 );
        table.addCell( cell02 );

        for ( int i = begin; i < finish; i++ 
        {
            GroupTerm term = new GroupTerm();

            int iterator = -1;
            int a = i + 1;

            while ( term.getTermID() != a )
            {
                iterator++;
                term = terms.get( iterator );
            }

            table.addCell( new PdfPCell( new Paragraph( conv.dateFromCalToString( term.getTerm() ), helvetica9 ) ) );
        }

        for ( int j = 0; j < children.size(); j++ )
        {
            table.addCell( new PdfPCell( new Paragraph( children.get( j ).getName() ) ) );
            table.addCell( new PdfPCell( new Paragraph( children.get( j ).getSurname() ) ) );
            for ( int k = 0; k < 10; k++ )
            {
                table.addCell( new PdfPCell( new Paragraph( "" ) ) );
            }
        }

        document.add( table );

        document.close();
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {

    }

    return pathForList;
}
```

And the problem is as goes: I generate pdf for a certain data, it creates List.pdf, it's well done. But, then I'm trying to generate one more for another set of data and generated file has size 0kb, and whene opened shows message "Adobe Reader could not open "List.pdf" beacuse it is either not a supported fily type or beacuse the file has been damaged".

PDF is generated in my web app and send via servlet in response so I'm oppening it through browser.

EDIT: My servlet code:

```
protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
    ... // Getting data here

    String path = pdf.generateList( group, terms, children, begin, finish );

    // download

    response.setContentType( "application/octet-stream" );
    response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=List.pdf" );

    ServletOutputStream out = null;

    try
    {
        File file = new File( path );
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream( file );
        out = response.getOutputStream();

        byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
        // copy binary contect to output stream
        while ( fileIn.read( outputByte, 0, 4096 ) != -1 )
        {
            out.write( outputByte, 0, 4096 );
        }
        fileIn.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        int i = 0;
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        if ( out != null )
        {
            out.close();
        }
    }
    finally
    {

    }

    response.sendRedirect( "calendar.jsp" );
}
```

EDIT: I also use iText to generate invoice in this app, and it works fine. All pdf's are correct, no matter what data I use.

What is wrong? I'm using the same method, only set of data is different.

Comment: If something goes wrong you'll never now it because of your empty `catch ( Exception e )` block.

Comment: Does document close the file stream? Flush and close manually.

Comment: @jlordo: catch has only simple logs implementation, it returns nothing for me.  Michael-O: I've added my servlet code above. When debbuging it seems that out and if streams are being closed (closed attribute changes false->true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. It was data itself. Method couldn't get data corectly and file was broken. I changed the way I send data and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your inner loop with:

```
int got;
while ( (got = fileIn.read( outputByte, 0, 4096 )) > 0) {
    out.write( outputByte, 0, got );
}
```

Your original loop always wrote 4096 bytes at the end of the file, but the last block of the file may be shorter than that, so your original loop wrote junk at the end of the HTTP response, padding it up to a multiple of 4096 bytes.

Comment: It didn't help, but this loop seems more reasonable then my, so I will keep it.

Comment: Problem is solved. It was data itself. Method couldn't get data corectly and file was broken. I changed the way I send data and it worked!

Comment: @eBEER: Add it as an answer and mark it accepted, so people now it's solved without reading every comment.